# pressing tab in snipmate plugin in vim triples the input

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

Snipmate triples my input. I do the following:

```
template[press tap here]
```

I get an expansion:

```
template <class T = >
class  {
public:
  () {}
  ~() {}
private:
};
```

which simply follows the definition in `~/.vim/vim-addons/snipmate-snippets/snippets/cpp.snippets`

```
# template
snippet template
    template <class ${1:T} = ${2}>
    class ${3:`Filename('$3', 'name')`} {
    public:
        $3() {}
        ~$3() {}
    private:
    };
```

I have no problem with inputting `{$1}` and `{$2}` tab stops but when I enter "lala " for `{$3}`, i get

```
template <class T = int>
class lala lala  alal {
public:
  lala  alal() {}
  ~lala  alal() {}
private:
};
```

snipmate syntax is pretty simple. i'm confused on what i'm doing wrong.

I installed snipmate through VAM

```
call vam#ActivateAddons(['snipmate-snippets'], {'auto_install' : 0})
```

Comment: cross-listed here https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/issues/111

Comment: Are you sure you get both `lala` and `alal`? Out of curiosity, what happens if the placeholder is `${4:…` instead of `${3:…`?

Comment: FYI, your snippet works normally with the original snipmate.

Comment: @romainl 4 breaks the tab jumping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I write, might be a bit biased, but I don't see any reason for using snipMate, when there is [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) by SirVer. Don't get me wrong snipMate is great, or better say - was great, but now it's just so far behind the UltiSnips plugin.

Be sure to see screencasts posted in the `README` of this project - to see the proof of what I said above.

Good luck.

Comment: yeah, I've started to use that too